# Add more heading levels

Tags: microsoft-word

I have MS Word document in which I would like to bring more hierarchy and later extract from it table of content. For this reason I'm using Headings from Styles palette. I see only 3 heading levels in my palette - Heading 1, Heading 2, Heading 3. How to get more hierarchy levels in MS Word?
[image]

Comment: By default, heading levels lower than three are hidden until the one above is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Heading 4 and following are configured as Hidden.

To unhide, do the following:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
  to show the Styles window
- Click on the third from the left icon on the bottom, labeled "Manage Styles"
- Select the tab "Recommended"
- Scroll up to the Heading group and click in turn on Heading 2, 3 and 4
- For each, click the Show button
- Select either "Only in this document" or "New documents based on this template",
  as required
- Click OK

You should now see all four styles in the banner's Styles group.